# Firefox discards URL when server connection times out or fails

Tags: firefox, browser, url

I have two problems with Firefox:

1. When I type a non-existent server into the address bar, such as

   ```
   http://xyz.example.com
   ```

   I get "server not found", but when I try to fix the address, Firefox forgets the URL and I need to start all over.
2. When the server is taking a long time to respond, and I click on the `X` icon to stop loading the page, the URL disappears as well

In both cases I want the URL to stay there in the address bar, so that I don't have to type it all over again. Is there a setting to make it do that?

I am using `Firefox (Iceweasel) 24.7` on `Debian Wheezy`

Comment: What version of `firefox` you have? It seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: Ah, never mind. I had the tab open which is why it seemed to remember.

Comment: I don't see this behaviour of #1 on - my Debian Wheezy, Iceeweasel v.31 - a Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine, v. 29 and v. 31 of firefox

Comment: Indeed, this behavior always annoyed me too. In such cases I copy the URL to clipboard before pressing <Enter>, so that later I can just paste it back.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour (point 1; didn't test point 2) with Firefox (Iceweasel) 24.7 on Debian 7.6 (that's the number in `/etc/debian_version`; no idea what codename that has). However for `gibtsnet.invalid` it adds a `www.` at the front where I didn't have one.

Comment: This is not really a good place for this question. Please file a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Answer (score 1):

This is standard behavior for firefox, I can observe the same in other operating systems. #2 does not happen if you write the address in a new tab, if that can help you. If you think this is a bug please file a bug with firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, whether this is a solution you prefer, but there is a newer iceweasel for debian available: [Debian Mozilla Team](http://mozilla.debian.net/)

To change to the current release, add this to your
/etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://mozilla.debian.net/ wheezy-backports iceweasel-release
```

and then update your system. (Or checkout the website for other releases).

PS: It also solves your other problem (264 codec).

Comment: I don't see any newer version of `Iceweasel` in in Debian backports. The version I am using (24.7.0) is the latest available in Debian Wheezy (both `wheezy` and `wheezy-backports`). Besides, are you sure upgrade to a higher version solves the problem?

Comment: If you expect the displayed version to change: read that sentence. It's about squeeze. If you added the given line and than update+upgraded your system, you should have v.31 by now.

Comment: Did you try it out?